# How to solve Error: GetCurrentCart: TrackingNotEnabledException from Sitecore Commerce 9 SXA

Tags: sitecore-commerce

Does anybody encountered the the TrackingNotEnabled exception on Sitecore Commerce 9 SXA Storefront?

It appears on almost every page and on any action that you do.

Below is the full exception error that I am receiving when I am accessing PDP.
[image: TrackingNotExabled - Sitecore Commerce 9 SXA]

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue appear when json models for Commerce are not deployed on xConnect folder.

I had same issue, because my json model it was copied to other folder not in my xconnect folder.

[image]

If you have same files like on image please rename to json and copy to correct folder.

[image]

Please have a look on this link :

https://hachweb.wordpress.com/2018/05/22/sitecore-xc-proper-update-of-xconnect/ .

It explain you what is wrong with your installation scripts.

Comment: Just to add what Vlad had mentioned above. Please rename the Models file to the "Name" attribute found inside the file and save as .json.